# Vs code не видит файл для ввода fstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, fstream

Нужно, чтобы программа открыла файл для начала, все вроде правильно указываю и путь к файлу из проводника и просто название файла, чтобы сам vs code нашел. Выдает такую ошибку, а в реплит результат ошибка открытия файла(хотябы выводит по условию ошибку)

Как мне это исправить? Или не понимаю как файл ввода вывода создавать на c++

[image: Код]
[image: Директория проекта]
[image: Ошибка]

```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <string> class Adress { private:
>     std::string city;
>     std::string street;
>     int houseNumber;
>     int flatNumber;
>     public:
>     Adress(std::string cityX, std::string valuestreetY, int valuehouseNumberX, int valueflatNumberY)
>     {
> 
>         city = cityX;
>         houseNumber = valuehouseNumberX;
>         street = valuestreetY;
>         flatNumber = valueflatNumberY;
>     }
>         void Resort(int i)
>     {
>         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
>         {
>             std::cout << city << "." << street << "." << houseNumber << "." << flatNumber << std::endl;
>         }
>     } }; int main() {
>         std::string path = "List.txt";
>     std::ifstream fin;
>     fin.open(path);
>         if (!fin.is_open())
>     {
>         std::cout << "Ошибка файла открытия" << std::endl;
>     }
>         else {
> 
>         std::cout << "Файл открыт" << std::endl;
>     }
>     }
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572875/microsoft-visual-studio-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD#comment2834981_1572875